# MutableLiveData<Pair<Float, Float>>() -> Val cannot be reassigned

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

In my ViewModel in Android project:

```
import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData

class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private var waitressCallContainerHeights = MutableLiveData<Pair<Int, Int>>()

    fun init() {
           waitressCallContainerHeights.value.first = 200
    }
}
```

But I get compile error in this line:

```
       waitressCallContainerHeights.value.first = 200

Val cannot be reassigned
```

I want to set **first** and **second** values in fun `init`

Comment: If you want to post new value you can do it like: waitressCallContainerHeights.postValue(Pair(100,200))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although your liveData is mutable, the Pair itself isn't. You need to do:
`waitressCallContainerHeights.value = Pair(200,300/* for example */)`

Answer (score 2):

You can also initialise the variable on the declaration itself with `apply`, something like this:

```
private var waitressCallContainerHeights = MutableLiveData<Pair<Int, Int>>().apply { value = Pair(200, 300) }
```